# My validateKey function is not returning expected key values

Tags: javascript, function, object

The goal of this function is to validate keys. If the keys are matched and no additional key present, it should return true. If there is no matching keys or they are less than the expected keys, it should return false.

The function `validateKeys(object, expectedKeys)` should return `true` or `false` in general. I posted detailed `code` for you to see the program flow

```
//running the function with `objectA` and `expectedKeys`
// should return `true`

const objectA = {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Jane Doe',
  age: 34,
  city: 'Chicago',
};

// running the function with `objectB` and `expectedKeys`
// should return `false`
const objectB = {
  id: 3,
  age: 33,
  city: 'Peoria',
};

const expectedKeys = ['id', 'name', 'age', 'city'];

function validateKeys(object, expectedKeys) {
  // your code goes here
    for (let i=0; i<expectedKeys.length;i++) {
        if (Object.keys(object).length === expectedKeys[i]) {
                return false;
        }else if (expectedKeys[i] < Object.keys(object) || Object.keys(object).length > expectedKeys[i] ) {
            return false;
        }else
        return;
    }
return true;
} 


/* From here down, you are not expected to 
   understand.... for now :)  


   Nothing to see here!

*/

function testIt() {
  const objectA = {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Jane Doe',
    age: 34,
    city: 'Chicago',
  };

  const objectB = {
    id: 3,
    age: 33,
    city: 'Peoria',
  };

  const objectC = {
    id: 9,
    name: 'Billy Bear',
    age: 62,
    city: 'Milwaukee',
    status: 'paused',
  };

  const objectD = {
    foo: 2,
    bar: 'Jane Doe',
    bizz: 34,
    bang: 'Chicago',
  };

  const expectedKeys = ['id', 'name', 'age', 'city'];

  if (typeof validateKeys(objectA, expectedKeys) !== 'boolean') {
    console.error('FAILURE: validateKeys should return a boolean value');
    return;
  }

  if (!validateKeys(objectA, expectedKeys)) {
    console.error(
      `FAILURE: running validateKeys with the following object and keys
      should return true but returned false:
      Object: ${JSON.stringify(objectA)}
      Expected keys: ${expectedKeys}`
    );
    return;
  }

  if (validateKeys(objectB, expectedKeys)) {
    console.error(
      `FAILURE: running validateKeys with the following object and keys
      should return false but returned true:
      Object: ${JSON.stringify(objectB)}
      Expected keys: ${expectedKeys}`
    );
    return;
  }

  if (validateKeys(objectC, expectedKeys)) {
    console.error(
      `FAILURE: running validateKeys with the following object and keys
      should return false but returned true:
      Object: ${JSON.stringify(objectC)}
      Expected keys: ${expectedKeys}`
    );
    return;
  }

  if (validateKeys(objectD, expectedKeys)) {
    console.error(
      `FAILURE: running validateKeys with the following object and keys
      should return false but returned true:
      Object: ${JSON.stringify(objectD)}
      Expected keys: ${expectedKeys}`
    );
    return;
  }

  console.log('SUCCESS: validateKeys is working');
}

testIt();
```

Comment: `else return;`  that seems to be one of your problems

Comment: This looks a lot like homework.

Comment: Your logic seems flawed, for example, what are you trying to do here `Object.keys(object).length === expectedKeys[i]`? One is giving the number of keys in a given object and the other is just a string with the value of a certain key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something along the lines of the following:

```
function validateKeys(object, expectedKeys) {
  let keys = Object.keys(object);

  // Check if both arrays have the same length
  // if not, we can exit early
  if (keys.length !== expectedKeys.length) {
    return false;
  }

  // If they do have the same length, then let's see if they
  // have all the keys, if not, return false
  for (let index = 0; index < expectedKeys.length; index++) {
    if (!expectedKeys.includes(keys[index])) {
        return false;
    };
  }

  // else return true, the keys are valid
  return true;
}
```

```js
//running the function with `objectA` and `expectedKeys`
// should return `true`

const objectA = {
  id: 2,
  name: "Jane Doe",
  age: 34,
  city: "Chicago",
};

// running the function with `objectB` and `expectedKeys`
// should return `false`
const objectB = {
  id: 3,
  age: 33,
  city: "Peoria",
};

const expectedKeys = ["id", "name", "age", "city"];

function validateKeys(object, expectedKeys) {
  let keys = Object.keys(object);
  
  // Check if both arrays have the same length
  // if not, we can exit early
  if (keys.length !== expectedKeys.length) {
    return false;
  }

  // If they do have the same length, then let's see if they
  // have all the keys, if not, return false
  for (let index = 0; index < expectedKeys.length; index++) {
    if (!expectedKeys.includes(keys[index])) {
        return false;
    };
  }

  // else return true, the keys are valid
  return true;
}

/* From here down, you are not expected to 
   understand.... for now :)  


   Nothing to see here!

*/

function testIt() {
  const objectA = {
    id: 2,
    name: "Jane Doe",
    age: 34,
    city: "Chicago",
  };

  const objectB = {
    id: 3,
    age: 33,
    city: "Peoria",
  };

  const objectC = {
    id: 9,
    name: "Billy Bear",
    age: 62,
    city: "Milwaukee",
    status: "paused",
  };

  const objectD = {
    foo: 2,
    bar: "Jane Doe",
    bizz: 34,
    bang: "Chicago",
  };

  const expectedKeys = ["id", "name", "age", "city"];

  if (typeof validateKeys(objectA, expectedKeys) !== "boolean") {
    console.error("FAILURE: validateKeys should return a boolean value");
    return;
  }

  if (!validateKeys(objectA, expectedKeys)) {
    console.error(
      `FAILURE: running validateKeys with the following object and keys
      should return true but returned false:
      Object: ${JSON.stringify(objectA)}
      Expected keys: ${expectedKeys}`
    );
    return;
  }

  if (validateKeys(objectB, expectedKeys)) {
    console.error(
      `FAILURE: running validateKeys with the following object and keys
      should return false but returned true:
      Object: ${JSON.stringify(objectB)}
      Expected keys: ${expectedKeys}`
    );
    return;
  }

  if (validateKeys(objectC, expectedKeys)) {
    console.error(
      `FAILURE: running validateKeys with the following object and keys
      should return false but returned true:
      Object: ${JSON.stringify(objectC)}
      Expected keys: ${expectedKeys}`
    );
    return;
  }

  if (validateKeys(objectD, expectedKeys)) {
    console.error(
      `FAILURE: running validateKeys with the following object and keys
      should return false but returned true:
      Object: ${JSON.stringify(objectD)}
      Expected keys: ${expectedKeys}`
    );
    return;
  }

  console.log("SUCCESS: validateKeys is working");
}

testIt();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing **string(expectedKeys[i])with number(length)** .
Javascript won't give you an error but it will always evaluate to false.
Also you have put a return inside a for loop which breaks the loop when it is 
encountered.

Comment: Please propose some solution in comment